# sudo ip link set can0 up Cannot find device "can0"

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

socketcan_interface,the ros package seems not working.I am  using Peak-Can USB at Ubuntu 18.04.3 and 16.04,melodic.I am sure pcan driver is installed fine,testing by pcan-viewer.
But neither can work,with same error"Cannot find device "can0"",when executing "sudo ip link set can0 up",really confused,wish for reply,thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336746/sudo-ip-link-set-can0-up-cannot-find-device-%22can0%22/) by [roslearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/48805/roslearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-11-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2019-11-04**:
sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000

Try this maybe before you give your command

Let me know, if it had worked, we can update it as an answer!

**Comment by [roslearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/48805/roslearner/) on 2019-11-04**:
No, it's not working.  Above I have said,it's just right this conmand "set ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000" causes the error occurrence---"cannot find device can0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have been solved. when building Peak Can usb driver,use this :
**make –C driver NET=NETDEV_SUPPORT**
referenced from PCAN-Driver-Linux_UserMan_eng.pdf  in driver/documentation folder.

---

Originally posted by [roslearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/48805/roslearner/) with karma: 16 on 2019-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0